# How to fetch header.html into index.html file using PHP?

Tags: php, header, multipage

I have an `header.html` file in which I have created a navigation section

I need to use this `header.html` file on multiple pages.

I want to know if it is possible to use `header.html` using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `include` or `file_get_contents`:

```
<?php include ('PATH_TO_YOUR_HTML'); ?>
```

Or this:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("PATH_TO_YOUR_HTML"); ?>
```